# Objective Best Practices for Plugin Development?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, wiki

Starting a community wiki to collect up ***objective*** best practices for plugin development. This question was inspired by [@EAMann's comments on wp-hackers](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2010-August/034246.html).

The idea is to collaborate on what objective best practices might be so that we can potentially eventually use them in some community collaboration review process.

**UPDATE:** After seeing the first few responses it becomes clear that we need to have only one idea/suggestion/best-practice per answer and people should review the list to ensure there are no duplicates before posting.

Comment: I really don't understand how community wiki should work on this (and the others) with SE properly, but maybe that's a question on meta. It will only pile up mostly dupes in answers.

Comment: @hakre: Great point. After seeing thing I'm going to add to the description that people should add only one idea per "answer" and I'm going to change my existing answer to be multiple answers.

Comment: ***Related Read:*** [Top 10 Most Common Mistakes in Wordpress Plugins](http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/09/top-10-most-common-coding-mistakes-in-wordpress-plugins/)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

## [Use Actions and Filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352)

If you think people would like to add or alter some data: **provide [apply_filters()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters) before returning**.

> P.S. One thing I find a bit disappointing and that your question addresses is the percentage of plugins that are designed only for end-users, i.e. that have no hooks of their own. Imagine if WordPress were designed like most plugins? It would be inflexible and a very niche solution.
>
> Maybe things would be different if WordPress were to have the ability to auto-install plugins on which other plugins depended? As it is I typically have to write a lot of the functionality I need from scratch because clients want things a certain way and the available plugins, while 90% there, don't allow me the flexibility to update the remaining 10%.
>
> I really do wish those leading the WordPress community would identify a way to ensure that plugins are rewarded for following best practices (such as adding in hooks for other developers) much like good answers are rewarded on a StackExchange site.

Let's take an example from [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352):

> Example: I want to do something in my plugin when someone retweets an article. If there was a custom hook in whatever the popular retweet plugin is that I could hook in to and fire off of, that would be great. There isn't, so I can modify their plugin to include it, but that only works for my copy, and I don't want to try to redistribute that.

### Related

- [Offer Extensible Forms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/789#789)

Answer (score 55):

### Load Scripts/CSS with `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style`

Plugins should not load / attempt to load duplicate versions of JS / CSS files, especially jQuery and other JS files included in WP Core.

Plugins should always use `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` when linking JS and CSS files and never directly via `<script>` tags.

#### Related

- [Re-Use existing functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/795#795)

Comment: **Suggestion**: Might be worth sticking a small note about using dependancies in there to(since it's part of the enqueue system).

Comment: Right, but better is that you register the styles and scripts before and then enqueue this scripts via ID. This is very fine for other developers to change the scripts or use it in custom plugins. Its also easier to change the order or create a summery file.

Comment: plus, Load scripts and styles on pages where required. http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html

Answer (score 50):

### I18n support

All output strings should be linked to an appropriate text domain to allow for internationalization by interested parties, even if the developer has no interest in translating their own plug-in.

Note that it is very important to load the language files during the `init` action so the user can hook into the action.

See the Codex: [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)

And also this article: [Loading WP language files the correctly](https://wpgeodirectory.com/loading-wordpress-language-files-correctly/).

### Since WordPress 4.6+

WP 4.6 changed the load order and the locations checked, it has made it a lot easier for developers and users.

Considering a plugin with a textdomain 'my-plugin', WordPress will now FIRST look for a translation file in:
**/wp-content/languages/plugins/my-plugin-en_US.mo**

If it fails to find one there it will then look for one where the plugin tells it to look (usualy in the pluigns 'language' folder if following the codex):
**/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/languages/my-plugin-en_US.mo**

Lastly if no language file is found it will check the default location of:
**/wp-content/languages/my-plugin-en_US.mo**

The first check was added in 4.6 and gives users a defined place to add a language file, as before they would need to know where the developer added the language file, now the user just needs to know the plugin's textdomain:
**/wp-content/languages/plugins/TEXTDOMAIN-LOCAL.mo**

---

### Below is the old way (Not relevant since WP 4.6+)

> [...]
>   Finally, I would like to point out that is important to **load custom user language files from WP_LANG_DIR before you load the language files that ship with the plugin**. When multiple mo-files are loaded for the same domain, the first found translation will be used. This way the language files provided by the plugin will serve as a fallback for strings not translated by the user.

```
public function load_plugin_textdomain()
{
    $domain = 'my-plugin';
    // The "plugin_locale" filter is also used in load_plugin_textdomain()
    $locale = apply_filters( 'plugin_locale', get_locale(), $domain );

    load_textdomain( 
            $domain, 
            WP_LANG_DIR . '/my-plugin/' . $domain . '-' . $locale . '.mo' 
    );
    load_plugin_textdomain( 
            $domain, 
            FALSE, 
            dirname( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '/languages/' 
    );
}
```

Comment: For me the most important one. It is not much of extra work to do it but one of the things you can make your plugin more useful for the millions of users who don't speak english as their first language. You don't even have to translate any word yourself, but prepare everything to be translated.

Comment: This is such a valuable, yet easy thing to do to, just wanted to say i agree and every plugin author should be doing this.

Answer (score 48):

### Ensure Plugins Generate No Errors with WP_DEBUG

Always test your plugins with [**`WP_DEBUG`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) turned on and ideally have it turned on throughout your development process. A plugin should not throw ANY errors with `WP_DEBUG` on. This includes deprecated notices and unchecked indexes.

To turn debugging on, edit your `wp-config.php` file so that the `WP_DEBUG` constant is set to `true`. See the [**Codex on Debug**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Debug) for more details.

Comment: Please see the UPDATE about having only best-practice per answer; can you split into multiple answers?

Comment: Sure, no problem. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, and wasn't your oversight, it was mine. I revised the question to ask for one best practice per answer based on @hakre's question about duplicates and how to make this work.

Comment: If I could upvote this answer twice, I would. It's so frustrating when I'm working on a dev site and have to turn WP_DEBUG off because a plugin I need to use is spewing warnings and notices all over the place.

Answer (score 42):

### First Use Existing Functions in WordPress Core

If you can: **use existing functions included in WordPress core** instead of writing your own. Only develop custom PHP functions when there is not an appropriate pre-existing function in WordPress core.

One benefit is you can use *"log deprecated notices"* to easily monitor functions that should be replaced. Another benefit is users can view the function documentation in the Codex and better understand what the plugin does even if they are not an experienced PHP developer.

#### Related

- [I18n support](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/752#752)
- [Load Scripts/CSS with wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/719#719)
- [Offer Extensible Forms](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/789#789)

Comment: One of the biggest problems here is learning that an appropriate existing function exists. What would be useful would be a place to post code and/or functionality needs to enable to community to comment on which function to best use. Maybe StackExchange could be used for this?

Comment: Puh. That would be pretty hard and i guess some sort of endless task. I think extending the codex in this way would be best, because it already exists.

Comment: I guess extending the codex and maybe linking from there to related stockexchange threads would be good enough.

Comment: A problem with that is that a lot of core isn't really structurally designed for reusability. I just had to copy and slightly modify half the image manipulation/metadata functions to create my own attachment-like behaving post-type, just because a function like downsize() calls some function that includes a hardcoded check for post-type='attachment'. There's lots of that like the inflexible wp_count_posts() being another example. Before you can really reuse core WP needs a complete refactoring.

Comment: Completely agree on this. My all time favorite example: `wp-login.php`. So, "If you can" was a good starter for the answer...

Answer (score 35):

### Uninstalling should remove all of a plugin's data

Upon being removed from a WordPress installation, **a plugin should delete all files, folders, database entries, and tables** which it created as well as the **option values** it created.

Plugins may offer an option to export/import settings, so that settings can be saved outside of WordPress prior to deletion.

### Related

- [Deactivation should not provoke Data-Loss](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/717#717)

Comment: This should be the default behavior, yes, but it should also prompt the user to keep some data ... like when uninstalling a video game asks you if you want to remove saved games and downloaded material.  A user might only be deactivating the plug-in for testing purposes and wouldn't want to go back through setting up their options when they reactivate it.

Comment: I'm only talking about when a plugin is completely removed, not when it is deactivated.

Comment: I understand that ... but sometimes I'll delete plug-ins so I can manually re-add them from a backup or beta version that's not yet hosted in the repository ...

Comment: @EAMann: For that and for migrating plugins to another server, a plugin should provide a mechanism to export and import settings.

Comment: @hakre - Import/Export: sounds like another best practice?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel: Done: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/925#925

Comment: This is so often disregarded. Only yesterday I found settings and entire tables blowing my database up. This is so annoying!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if i agree. If the plugin creates it's own db tables, yes, but with the new custom post types being used for everything, we'll (hopefully) soon have plugins sharing post types and so on. This can make 'data removal' quite a tricky topic.

Comment: I've seen a few plugins offer an "Uninstall" button in their settings with big red warnings it will delete all data.  This is separate from de-activation, and I think a great way to handle it.  Not everyone uses the "Delete" button to remove a plugin.

Comment: So what is the best practice when a plugin creates a custom post type and enters data into that post type? Should that data be deleted or not? If not, are there any plugins we can use as a guide for implementing the same 'uninstall' button?

Comment: I have to disagree with this.  An uninstall button in the plugin is great, but simply deleting the plugin shouldn't trigger database changes with out lots of warning.

Answer (score 34):

### Prevent SQL Injection with Input Data

A plugin *should* **sanitize all user input retrieved directly or indirectly (e.g. via `$_POST` or `$_GET`**) before using input values to query the MySQL database.

See: [Formatting SQL statements](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#Formatting_SQL_statements).

Comment: You should also sanitize data coming _out_ of the database. Basically, never trust any data that isn't hardcoded. http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation is a good reference too.

Answer (score 31):

### Prefix All Global Namespace Items

A plugin should properly prefix ALL global namespace items (constants, functions, classes, variables, even things like custom taxonomies, post types, widgets, etc.). For example, do not create a function called `init()`; instead, name it something like `jpb_init()`.

Its common  should use a three or four letter prefix in front of names or to make use of the [PHP Namespace Feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php). Compare: [Single-letter prefix for PHP class constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479287/single-letter-prefix-for-php-class-constants)

#### Related

- [Global Namespace is a limited Resource](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/771#771)

Comment: I would use global functions *very* sparingly, even when prefixed. Instead use classes with a namespace. If you want to have utility/template functions you can use a static function within a class.

Answer (score 31):

##### Use a class and object-oriented PHP code

There's no reason not to write clean, object-oriented PHP code. PHP4 is not supported since 2008. Of course, you can prefix all your function names to end up with `endlessly_long_function_names_with_lots_of_underscores`, but it's much easier to just write a simple class and bundle everything in that. Also, put your class in a separate file and name it accordingly so you can easily extend and maintain it:

```
// in functions.php
require 'inc/class-my-cool-plugin.php';
new MyCoolPlugin();

// in inc/class-my-cool-plugin.php
class MyCoolPlugin {
    function __construct() {
        // add filter hooks, wp_enqueue_script, etc.
        
        // To assign a method from your class to a WP 
        // function do something like this
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, "admin"]);
    }
    
    public function admin() {
        // public methods, for use outside of the class
        // Note that methods used in other WP functions 
        // (such as add_action) should be public
    }
    
    private function somethingelse() {
        // methods you only use inside this class
    }
}
```

Comment: dont use new MyCoolPlugin();
i think is better you hook in WP via Hook: plugins_loaded

Comment: Not sure about that. According to the codex plugins_loaded is one of the very first things loaded, so i think it makes little difference to either do a construct like this, or add it as an action.

Comment: it is just one of those best practices that make it nicer for everyone.

Comment: As far as I can see adding a hook into plugins_loaded makes zero improvements, and wouldn't be a best practice since there isn't any improvements, if anything there are is increase memory usage, decreased speed as it has to go through an action instead of the actions just being added. Also using OO shouldn't be considered a best practice.

Comment: Is there agreement about how to create the object, should it be via hook or not?

Comment: This is a great idea, but you have to be careful to make sure you only include the class file if the server is PHP5. See https://github.com/iandunn/WordPress-Plugin-Skeleton/blob/master/bootstrap.php for an example.

Comment: @IanDunn: if you want PHP4 support, but PHP4 support has been dropped since 2008, over 4 years ago. There's no reason to still be using PHP4-specific checks.

Answer (score 26):

### Deactivation should not provoke Data-Loss

A plugin *should not* **delete any of its data upon *deactivation***.

#### Related

- [Uninstall should remove all plugin's data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/716#716)

Answer (score 23):

Only include files that you need...

If you're in the front end, don't include code that relates to the admin area.

Answer (score 21):

### Announce Data-Loss on Plugin Uninstallation

**Upon uninstallation** a plugin *should* **prompt a user that it will be deleting it's data** and receive a confirmation that the user is okay with deleting the data before doing so and a plugin *should* also *allow the user the option to keep the data* upon uninstallation. (This idea from @EAMann.)

#### Related

- [Uninstall should remove all plugin's data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/716#716)
- [Deactivation should not provoke to Data-Loss](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/717#717)

Comment: Wordpress itselfs displays a warning message in the admin, that this happens (at least in trunk right now).

Comment: Aside from the warning message displayed by WordPress, it is impossible for the plugin to prompt the user, since at the time of uninstallation it is already deactivated. But see [ticket #20578](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20578).

Answer (score 19):

### Minimize Names Added to the Global Namespace

A plugin *should* **reduce it's impact** as much as possible by **minimizing the number of names it adds to the global namespace**.

This can be done by encapsulating the plugin's functions into a class or by using the [PHP namespaces feature](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php). Prefixing everything can help as well but is not that flexible.

Next to functions and classes, a plugin *should not* introduce global variables. Using classes normally obsoletes them and it simplifies plugin maintenance.

#### Related

- [Prefix Properly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/755#755)

Comment: Can you please move the *"should not introduce global variables"* to it's own answer? That is related by separate from this question and actually one I'd like to debate (both because I think I may disagree is special cases and because I want to learn from the opinions of others.)

Answer (score 19):

### Let plugin's folder name be changed

/plugins/pluginname/{various}

The "pluginname" used for the folder should always be changeable.

This is normally handled by defining constants and consistantly using them throughout the plugin.

Needless to say many popular plugins are sinners.

## Related:

- [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) for easy linking to resources, included with plugin.

Comment: Renaming the plugin's folder will cause automated updates to break, so I'm not sure it's the best thing to be doing.

Comment: You'd have to re-enable the plugin after doing the change anyway(the name change would likely result in plugin deactivation), at which point WP will re-create or update the appropriate DB entries related to plugins(so it wouldn't break updates at all).

Comment: Instead of using a constant, use `plugin_basename(__FILE__)` to figure the plugin's local name out. That is useful for having copies of the same plugin (testing, multiple accounts elsewhere but only one per plugin, ...), too.

Answer (score 19):

#### Use WordPress (built in) Error handling

Don't just `return;` if some user input was wrong. Deliver them some information about was was done wrong.

```
function some_example_fn( $args = array() ) 
{
    // If value was not set, build an error message
    if ( ! isset( $args['some_value'] ) )
        $error = new WP_Error( 'some_value', sprintf( __( 'You have forgotten to specify the %1$s for your function. %2$s Error triggered inside %3$s on line %4$s.', TEXTDOMAIN ), '$args[\'some_value\']', "\n", __FILE__, __LINE__ ) );

    // die & print error message & code - for admins only!
    if ( isset( $error ) && is_wp_error( $error ) && current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) 
        wp_die( $error->get_error_code(), 'Theme Error: Missing Argument' );

    // Elseif no error was triggered continue...
}
```

---

#### One error (object) for all

You can set up a global error object for your theme or plugin during the bootstrap:

```
function bootstrap_the_theme()
{
    global $prefix_error, $prefix_theme_name;
    // Take the theme name as error ID:
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    $prefix_theme_name = $theme_data->Name;
    $prefix_error = new WP_Error( $theme_data->Name );

    include // whatever, etc...
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'bootstrap_the_theme' );
```

Later you can add unlimited Errors on demand:

```
function some_theme_fn( $args )
{
    global $prefix_error, $prefix_theme_name;
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    if ( ! $args['whatever'] && current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) // some required value not set
        $prefix_error->add( $prefix_theme_name, sprintf( 'The function %1$s needs the argument %2$s set.', __FUNCTION__, '$args[\'whatever\']' ) );

    // continue function...
}
```

Then you can fetch them all at the end of your theme. This way you don't interrupt rendering the page and can still output all your errors for developing

```
function dump_theme_errors()
{
    global $prefix_error, $prefix_theme_name;

    // Not an admin? OR: No error(s)?
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ! is_wp_error( $prefix_error ) )
        return;

    $theme_errors = $prefix_error->get_error_messages( $prefix_theme_name );
    echo '<h3>Theme Errors</h3>';
    foreach ( $theme_errors as $error )
        echo "{$error}\n";
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'dump_theme_errors' );
```

---

You can find further information at [this Q](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/how-to-use-wp-error-data-argument). A related ticket to fix the "working together" of `WP_Error` and `wp_die()` is linked from there and another ticket will follow. Comments, critics & such is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you instantiate a WP_Error object if you only access it's properties and never pass the instance as an object?

Comment: @ProfK I reworked it to be shorter and the title/content for `wp_die();` was wrong (reversed). About your Q) I don't completely get it. When you set up an instance of the WP_Error class you have full access to its data via functions like `get_error_code();`, `get_error_message();`, `get_error_data();` and the plural versions. You could also only instantiate it once at the bootstrap of your theme or plugin and simply use `$error->add();` to fill other errors and finally output it in the footer with `$error->get_error_messages();` to catch them all.

Comment: @ProfK I'll post future updates to [this Q](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32309/how-to-use-wp-error-data-argument). I'm currently inspecting the behavior of the wp error class and want to write a ticket about a public theme error API (draft already done). You'll find a link to another ticket that brings `WP_Error` and `wp_die()` closer together (already has a patch) at the bottom of the Q. Any comment, suggestions, critics and else is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

### Comment using PhpDoc

Best practice is close to the PhpDoc style.
If you don't use an IDE like "Eclipse", you can just take a look [at the PhpDoc Manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.pkg.html).

You don't have to know exactly how this works. Professional Developers can read the code anyway and just need this as a summary. Hobby coders and users might appreciate the way you explain it on the same knowledge level.

Answer (score 17):

### Use the Settings API before add_option

Instead of adding options to the DB via the add_option function, you should store them as an array with using the [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) that takes care of everything for you.

### Use the Theme Modifications API before add_option

The [Modifications API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Modification_API) is a pretty simple construct and a safe way that allows adding and retrieving options. Everything gets saved as serialized value in your database. Easy, safe & simple.

Comment: And furthermore, use `update_option` and never `add_option`, the update function will create the option when it does not exist.. :)

Comment: I wouldn't say never use `add_option`. There is a good use case for `add_option` where if the option is already set, it isn't changed, so I use it in activation to preserve possibly already existing user preferences.

Comment: Another use case for `add_option` is when you want to explicitly disable auto loading. `update_option` will force autoload to true, so you want to disable autoload, use `add_option` when initially creating the option.

Answer (score 16):

### Protect Plugin Users Privacy

(Previously: Anonymous API Communication)

If a plug-in communicates with an external system or API (e.g. some Webservice), it should do so anonymously or provide the user with an anonymous option that ensures that no data related to the user of the plugin leaks to a second party uncontrolled.

Answer (score 15):

### Host Plugins on WordPress.org

Use the [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) repository [provided on WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add/) for hosting plugins. It makes for an easier update user-experience and if you've never used SVN before, it gets you to actually understand by using it in a context that justifies it.

Answer (score 15):

### Provide Access Control by Using Permissions

In many instances, users may not want everyone to have access to areas created by your plugin especially with plugins that do multiple complex operations, a single hardcoded capability check may not be enough.

At the very least, have appropriate capability checks for all of the different kind of procedures your plugin can be used for.

Answer (score 12):

## Organize your code

It's alway hard to read code that's not written in the order it get's executed. First include/require, define, wp_enqueue_style & _script, etc., then the functions that the plugin/theme needs and at last the builder (ex. admin screen, stuff that integrates in the theme, etc.).

Try to separate things like css and js in their own folders. Also try to do this with functions that are only helpers, like array flatteners and similar. Keeping the "main" file as clean and easy to read as possible is a way that helps users, developers and you, when you try to update in a year and haven't seen the code for a longer time.

It's also good to have a structure you repeat often, so you always find your way through. Developing in a known structure on different projects will give you time to make it better and even if your client switches to another developer, you will never hear "he left a chaos". This builds your reputation and should be a long term goal.

Comment: I fear this is a bit too much about style that people would debate and not objective best practices with which all respected people would agree. It's very important we only address objective best practices so that people will be willing to agree to "bless" the list as opposed to having controversial items, no matter how well meant.

Answer (score 12):

### Import / Export Plugin Settings

It's not that common across plugins, but if your plugin has (some) settings, it *should* **provide Import / Export of data like configuration and user input**.

Import/Export improves the usability of a plugin.

An example-plugin that has such an import and export functionality (and as well an undo mechanism) is [Breadcrumb NavXT (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/) (full disclosure: some little code by me in there, most has been done by mtekk).

#### Related

- [Uninstall should remove all plugin's data](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/716#716)
- [Deactivation should not provoke Data-Loss](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/717#717)

Answer (score 11):

## Die with style

**die in a decent manner**
All of a plugins (and even themes) functions should use `wp_die()` in critical places to offer the user a little information on what had happened. Php errors are annoying and `wp_die` can give the user a nice styled message on what the plugin (or they) did wrong. Plus, if the user has debugging deactivated the plugin will just break.

Using `wp_die()` also helps that your plugins / themes are compatible with the [wordpress testsuite](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/703/tutorials-for-unit-testing-in-wordpress-and-for-unit-test-svn-wordpress-org).

Related:

- [Use WP Error handling](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/16246#16246)

Answer (score 11):

## Provide Help Screens for users

It is nicer to say RTFM (click help) as an answer than having to answer the question time and time again.

```
/**
  * Add contextual help for this screen
  * 
  * @param $rtfm
  * @uses get_current_screen
  */ 
  function ContextualHelp( /*string*/ $rtfm) 
  { 
     $current_screen = get_current_screen();
     if ($current_screen->id == $this->_pageid) 
     {
        $rtfm .= '<h3>The WordPress Plugin - Screen A</h3>';
        $rtfm .= '<p>Here are some tips: donate to me ' .
     }
     return $rtfm; 
  }
add_action('contextual_help', array($this,'ContextualHelp'),1,1);
```

**update / note:** (see comments from kaiser): the above example is to be used in a class

Comment: Should be in everyones toolbox (as long as you have to explain a specifc admin ui screen). +1

Comment: Btw: You should mention, that this is meant to reside in a Class and how to interact with $this->_page_id & how it would be if you'd add the action hook from a functions.php or a plugin file without a Class.

Answer (score 10):

## Offer Extensible Forms

When a plugin offers the possiblity to input data, it should always have a hook at the end, right before the "submit" and/or "reset" button, so developers can easily extend the form with not only fields, but buttons too.

See: [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API)

### Related

- [Use Actions and Filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/730#730)
- [Re-Use existing functions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/795#795)
- [I18n support](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/752#752)

Answer (score 9):

include function always via Hook, not directly.

Example:

- Dont use for include the class of the plugin via new without hook
- Use the Hook plugins_loaded

  ```
  // add the class to WP                                   
  function my_plugin_start() {                                                               
      new my_plugin();   
  }                                                        
  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'my_plugin_start' );
  ```

**Update:**
a small live example: [Plugin-svn-trunk-page](http://svn.wp-plugins.org/filter-rewrite-rules/trunk/filter-rewrite-rules.php)
and a pseudo example

```
//avoid direct calls to this file where wp core files not present
if (!function_exists ('add_action')) {
        header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
        header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
        exit();
}

if ( !class_exists( 'plugin_class' ) ) {
    class plugin_class {

        function __construct() {
        }

    } // end class

    function plugin_start() {

        new plugin_class();
    }

    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'plugin_start' );
} // end class_exists
```

You can also load via mu_plugins_loaded on multisite-install, see the codex for action reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
Also here do you see, how inlcude wP with this hook: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/plugins_loaded?version=2.1&file=wp-settings.php
I uses this very often and its not so hard and early, better as an hard new class();

Comment: @bueltige --- could you explain this one a bit more

Comment: a small live example: [Plugin-svn-trunk-page]http://svn.wp-plugins.org/filter-rewrite-rules/trunk/filter-rewrite-rules.php 
and a pseudo example


`//avoid direct calls to this file where wp core files not present
if (!function_exists ('add_action')) {
  header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
  header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
  exit();
}

if ( !class_exists( 'plugin_class' ) ) {
 class plugin_class {
  
  function __construct() {
  }
  
 } // end class
 
 function plugin_start() {
 
  new plugin_class();
 }
  
 add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'plugin_start' );
} // end class_exists`

Comment: @Netconstructor.co - i have update the thread, the comment ist ugly for code

Answer (score 8):

### License Plugins under a GPL Compatible License

Plug-ins and themes *should* be licensed under a WordPress-compatible license. This enables them to be re-distributed with WordPress as a "program." A recommended license is [the GPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html). *Take care that all code libraries included with the plug-in are compatible with the same license.*

(This has [been a problem](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/377/gpl-and-plugins) and serious [point of debate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5/am-i-allowed-to-license-my-wordpress-theme-under-the-agpl) both in the past and [present](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14685).)

Comment: Let's leave that with GPL compatibility for the moment: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14685

Answer (score 8):

Your plugin description should accurately detail the functions of your plugin. There are 10 featured post plugins. All of them display featured posts, yet many have different features. It should be easy to compare your plugin to similar plugins by reading the description.

You should avoid bragging about how simple your plugin is unless it really is very basic. You should include useful links in the description like the link to the settings.

Answer (score 7):

### Minimize Side-effects of Remote Datasources and Webservices

A Plugin *should* **Cache/Shield Webservice** and/or **XMLRPC/SOAP requests through a caching/data-provider layer** if you use them so to not making front-requests waiting for (slow) webservice response.

That includes the download of RSS feed and other pages. Design your plugins that they request data in background.

One possible STEP is (Take posting to ping.fm as an example):
Create a buffer table, let's say: 
ping_fm_buffer_post(
date, time, message, submitted_time, status
)

1. For every time you want to submit update to ping.fm, add it to this table.
2. Now, we need to create a plugin to handle this data. This plugin will run via crontab to check for every update that's not submitted yet
3. Because we have this table, we can also list every message submitted to ping.fm and check each post's status. Just in case there's problem on ping.fm's side, we can re-submit it.

Comment: I don't really understand where you are exactly headed with this. Can you provide some links to supporting material?

Comment: Also, I'm not exactly sure what *"Net Overhead"* is. Isn't there a better term? If it's more clear it will be a better objective rule. And *Prevent"* is impossible; *"Minimize"* instead?

Comment: You're (probably) right. Bad wording and prevent is never possible, minimize better fits.

Answer (score 7):

### Use Proper Names

**Name hooks and filters** (classes, functions and vars), so **that people can identify them in even a year**, when they don't remember any more, where that piece of cake or code comes from. It doesn't matter if hook/filter names get long. Ex. youruniquename_hook/filter_whatitdoes.

- If your file contains a class named "dbdbInit", then the file that contains the class should be named "`dbdbInit.class.php`".
- If you got inside your `dbdbInit`-class a function that registers ex. custom_post_types, then call it `register_custom_post_types()`.
- If you got an array that contains the names for custom_post_types, then call the variable where the array is assigned `$custom_post_type_names`.
- If you got a function that handles an array write `function array_handler( $array ) { // handle the array}`..
- Just try to name things in a way that you know what the sign does/where it belongs to by it's name.

Another thing: If you have to debug stuff then, in 99% of all cases, you get all your messages for not only your code, but for wordpress too. So try to use the same prefix ex. "`dbdb`" for your classes, public functions and variables/objects. This way you can find them easily between hundreds of files. (Wordpress loads 64 files before your theme and about 1,550 functions, not talking about hooks and filters.)

Comment: I really have no clear idea what this means. It's first sentence is not a complete sentence. This needs to be rewritten and clarified.

Comment: sticking to the WP standards when naming files and functions is also nice, e.g. "class-db-init.php" http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards

Answer (score 7):

## Care about future WordPress & theme versions

Note: After re-reading this advice, I now step back from this practice as checking every function for existence may slow down your site.

**Check if functions are deprecated** directly in your theme.

This is a "could be like that" example.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_some_fn' ) ) 
{
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();
    $error = new WP_Error( 'wp_some_fn', sprintf( __( 'The function %1$s is deprecated. Please inform the author', TEXTDOMAIN ), "Theme: {$theme_data->Name}: Version {$theme_data->Version}" );

    // abort
    if ( is_wp_error( $error ) )
        return print $error->get_error_message();
} 
// else if no error - the function works and exists
wp_some_fn();
```

For proper/best practice error handling see this answer: [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/797#797)

You could drop even the $cause into the function. This will help you and your users to keep on track with functions or classes in your theme that might change.

Answer (score 7):

## Test your plugin

We should definitively have some testing tools on our plugin development environment.

Based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9429/unit-testing-for-plugin-development/9448#9448) by [Ethan Seifert](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/984/ethan-seifert) to a testing question, these are good practices to follow:

- Your Unit Testing should test the smallest amount of behavior that a class can perform.
- When you get up to the level of functional testing this is where you can test you code with Wordpress dependencies.
- Depending on what your plugin does -- consider using Selenium-based tests which test for the presence of data in the DOM by using IDs

Comment: While testing is important, saying unit tests should test the smallest instead of the greatest seems unwise. If you're having difficulty testing the WordPress dependent issues then just dive into the WordPress core, you'll find a whole bunch of internal global variables which you can use to see if items have worked.

Comment: But covering the smallest first is basic, so that you can reach the functional testing with WordPress as the answer says, isn't that right?

Comment: This is a plugin not an application, can you test a Java application without Java Runtime? Yes, by writing Java as a mockup and then test your plugin. Chances are the bugs are in your mockup. *) disclaimer or compiling it to native code.

Answer (score 7):

**Use WordPress's Coding Standards**

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards

You know how much easier it is to update code you've worked on vs. code someone else has put together?  Coding standards make it easier for any developer working on a project to come in and see what's going on.

We know your plugin or theme is your own, and the way you break your lines and add your curly braces is an expression of your individuality.  Every indent is a carefully thought-out statement.  But with your custom code, you're contributing to WordPress, even if your code isn't in the core application.  Coding standards help developers quickly get up-to-speed with your code.

Answer (score 6):

### Decouple from WordPress core code

A Plugin *should* **reduce the impact of the WordPress API to the needed minimum** so to seperate plugin code from WordPress code. This reduces the impact of changes within the WordPress codebase on the plugin. Additionally this improves the cross-version compatibility of your plugin code.

This does not mean to not use WordPress functions (use them, as [*Re-Use existing functions*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development/795#795) suggests), but not to mesh your code with WordPress functions too much but to seperate your plugins business logic from WordPress functionality.

Comment: I'm strugglying with the wording on this. Do you mean that a plugin should use the WordPress API whenever possible rather than directly accessing SQL tables and/or directly accessing global variables?

Comment: Well. Once we had to deal with form data in a project, so to access $_REQUEST. Then they changed the slashing inside that. So instead of using $_REQUEST, use a function that has a single call to $_REQUEST for the whole plugin. In case slashing changes, only this function needs to be changed. This is not against using Wordpress API but to make the plugin decouple to it so you can better react to changes in WP core. This helps to maintain your plugins in the long run. For just some gadget, this is not necessary.

Comment: Having been a developer on and off for 23 years I've seen many cycles and many suggested best practices come and go. I've seen the pendulum swing wide both ways. I now believe in moderation. In my earlier years I abstracted everything but I learned that abstraction adds complexity that is often worse than the expected benefit. When we see something that causes us trouble as people we immediately seize upon ways to protect ourselves from it in the future but often the medicine is more harmful than the disease. In the USA Sarbanes-Oxley is an example of this.

Comment: I used to believe global variables were just bad. And then I worked with WordPress and you know what, they have their benefits when used in moderation. I could write a book on this subject (though I don't plan on it; too much work for too little reward.) Where do I see the pendulum now? Simplicity has the highest value. It's probably better not to abstract and then just solve the problems when and if they arise rather than spinning many more cycles in fear that they might. So I'm inclined to vote this one down.

Comment: Just from a short question i asked on wp-hackers: They hate you if you use global variables like `$wp_taxonomies`, because they are "internal" (i know there are some that should be used like `$wp_query` or `$post`)...

Comment: @kaiser - Either something is internal or changing will break backwards compatibility. So much for the global namespace in wordpress.

Comment: @hakre: Who said something about changing? Retrieving and using data from this is what i'm talking about. There is not always a function that does what you need and before i end up doing custom sql queries i just use them.

Comment: @kaiser: Changing in the meaning that the data will change in these vars. Or even *you* wanted to change even data in global arrays? ;) It's a hell of a time-saver. Even if things break with a new version, thats quick to fix.

Comment: @hakre: No, i'm not playing/messing around inside the data that get's served by global $vars. And yes: better go this way and break in a future version instead of messing around with 5 functions that could also get depracated (and not marked as this) and then fix it later in 5 mins. Time saver: +1.

Answer (score 6):

### Use wp options for plugin output strings

In order to make the plugin easily used and customizable, all the output strings should be modifiable.
The best way to do that is use wp-options to store the output strings and provide backend to change the default values.
Plugin shouldn't use displayed strings that cannot be easily changed using the plugin backend.

For example:
Sociable - gives you the ability to change the sentence that appears before the icons part "share and enjoy:"

Comment: What exactly is a "plugin string?" Can you give use-case examples? Also, please write in complete sentences so this can be a more valuable resource.

Comment: If you have internationalisation, this should be redundant.

Comment: I disagree. It makes it easier for end users, but harder for developers. As Raphael said, i18n should be used instead.

Comment: I second Raphael and scribu. gettext functions are easy to filter, there is no need to redundantly store textual content in database.

Answer (score 4):

#### Use uninstall, activate and deactivate hooks

There are three different hooks for this:

- Uninstall `register_uninstall_hook();`
- Deactivation `register_deactivation_hook();`
- Activation `register_activation_hook();`

[A detailed instruction with a working example can be found here.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979).