# Can I use an array to create multiple tables?

Tags: plugin-development, table

I followed the codex page on how to make tables in the wordpress database with a plugin and was able to understand and get it to work  However, the plugin I'm developing has the need for many tables along with joining tables and to code each table individually would be time consuming to say the least.

Is there a way to create a batch of tables using an array() and loop function?

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL tables?

Comment: Yes, MySQL tables that are created from a php plugin.  Here's the codex page that I modeled my plugin after http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: So what you are suggesting is that the best way to create a set of tables with an array is if each table had the same or similar fields?  If that is the case, then I guess I'll be writing a script for each required table.  Thanks!

Comment: Deleted that comment, posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes, you can build your tables from an array but unless your tables are very similar, and they probably aren't, I don't know that doing that will be any less work than just writing out the definitions. That is, even if you used an array, you'd need to define each table from scratch and then Loop over the array to create the tables. You could save yourself some work, but I doubt it would be very much.

And you seem to be on the right track as far as the WordPress parts of this. That Codex page describes the canonical way to create tables, and you say you have that working.

You can cheat, though, and build your tables in PhpMyAdmin, then dump the definitions :)

Comment: Yes, it is working just fine.  I did make a couple of changes as suggested by Dennis on this post  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4276/creating-two-database-tables-via-plugin?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I ended up modeling the tables in MySQL Workbench and got the sql code from pushing out the new tables.