# Include jQuery (or anything) inside Custom Options Panel's <head> tag

Tags: theme-development

The title pretty much explains exactly what I'm trying to do. If someone could help me out, that would be awesome. Thanks!

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way to include files for scripts you can use the hook "admin_print_scripts"

and include your scripts [with wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

for example:

```
<?php 
add_action('admin_print_scripts','my_scripts');
function my_scripts(){
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
?>
```

and for styles use the hook "admin_print_styles" and include you styles with [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

for example:

```
<?php 
add_action('admin_print_styles','my_styles');
function my_styles(){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'myPluginStylesheet', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/myPlugin/stylesheet.css' );
}
?>
```

Hope This Helps.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery should already be loaded, it's used throughout the admin area of WordPress.

If you want to include some of your own jQuery, just enqueue the script and set jQuery as a dependancy.

```
add_action('admin_print_scripts-%HANDLE%','enqueue_my_script');
function enqueue_my_script(){
    // Uncomment line below if using inside a plugin
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', plugins_url( 'myfile.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    // Uncomment line below if using inside theme functions.php
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) . '/myfile.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

%HANDLE% should be appropriately changed for the handle of your registered page, it's the fifth parameter in `add_menu_page` and the fourth in `add_submenu_page` and others such as `add_theme_page`.

This method will ensure the enqueue is only made for your specific custom page, and not *every* admin page.

I also covered using registered handles to selectively enqueue in **[URLs of plugin resources?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7697/urls-of-plugin-resources)**

Hope that helps..