# WordPress Plugin Development from Scratch. How?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I would like to learn how to create a plugin from scratch, there are tons of tutorials out there on the internet, but they are either premium or not a reliable resource. would like to know which are the best resources available on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very first advice from me will be: Don't follow the tutorials on the tutorial sites blindly they are full of bad coding practices.

Some of the resources that I follow:

- [Mark on Wordpress](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/)
- [Justin Tad Lock](http://justintadlock.com/) (You can also buy the copy of his e-book Professional Wordpress Plugin Development)
- [Otto on Wordpress](http://ottopress.com/)
- [scribu's development blog](http://scribu.net/)

And here is the list of Specific tutorials that you should consider going through, some are old but are still valid.

- http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2006/03/04/wp-tutorial-your-first-wp-plugin/
- http://www.devlounge.net/extras/how-to-write-a-wordpress-plugin

Answer (score 3):

I guess [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development) says nearly all

Answer (score 1):

Additional to all above tutorials i recommend the following which best suites a beginner

- https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/noob-plugin-diary/
- http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/
- https://wpadverts.com/blog/how-to-create-wordpress-plugin-from-a-scratch/
- https://wpshout.com/making-first-plugin-live/

Best wishes

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to create a plugin too.

First place that I would like to suggest you to walk through is [Writing a Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) from Wordpress Codex.

Answer (score 0):

Follow,What Hameedullah Khan Said.Additionally,I would like to suggest to you read the WordPress Codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

http://www.slideshare.net/davidfcarr/introduction-to-plugin-programming-wordcamp-miami-2011

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this Wordpress Plugin Development series of video tutorials by Alessandro Castellani:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0l7JTie_6jM&list=PLriKzYyLb28kR_CPMz8uierDWC2y3znI2

They're completely free, and they're great. He also has videos on other Wordpress related topics, including a fantastic 64-videos series on how to create a Wordpress theme from scratch. Really good stuff.