# What are some examples of well-written plugins that exemplify wordpress plugin best practices?

Tags: plugins

I've searched through the stack exchange for wordpress and was unable to come up with an answer to this question.  All of the wordpress codex's examples and external resources come from 2004-2006. I'd love an example of a popular Wordpress plugin that is also well-written. As I'm fairly new to programming (less than 1 year in), this would be immensely helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy the Professional WordPress Plugin Development book from Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Professional-WordPress-Plugin-Development-Williams/dp/0470916222](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470916222)  I'm learning tons from it and it's packed full of good information about best practices. It will walk you through building your own plugin with lots of code samples.  I cannot recommend it enough. If you're serious about learning to write plugins then this is one book you absolutely must buy.

Comment: Seconded.  Full of nice tips an tricks.   Just got this last week and learned so much more than what you can scrounge around the net and then some.

Comment: Hey Polly, I just wanted to thank you for informing about this book. I purchased it and it is really helping not only in learning about Wordpress plugins abut also about best practices in the field as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [highest voted Qs on WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes)

Comment: +1 , more specifically http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/715/objective-best-practices-for-plugin-development

Answer (score 2):

Download some plugins from well respected developers to see how they code their stuff.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty good WP developers out there. To cite only one, core WP developer [Mark Jaquith's plugins](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/markjaquith/) are a good inspiration.