# register_activation_hook() not activate plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I am writing a plugin that on the activation must create a new table in database.

To do this i am using:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'createTable' );
```

When i run the activation, my plugin creates the new table in the database but when the plugin-page is reloaded my plugin is listed as not active.
So i have still the links:

activate|delete.

Why this happends? how to fix?

Here is my function:

```
    function createTable(){


    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
    if (!$link) {
        die( 'Could not connect: ' . mysql_error() );
    }
    mysql_select_db (db_name); 

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS UsersExtra (
      user_id INT NOT NULL,
      first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      address VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
      city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
      province CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      postcode CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
      interests TEXT NULL,
      bio TEXT NULL,
      signature TEXT NULL,
      skills TEXT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
      FULLTEXT KEY (interests, skills)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";

    mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
    mysql_close($link);

}
```

Comment: there must be some error in createTable function - turn on wp_debug in your wp-config and debug it on your own, or provide us with source code of that function

Comment: What does `FILE` means in `register_activation_hook( FILE, 'createTable' );`? Are code fragments you've pasted both resides in the main plugin file?

Comment: @MaxYudin Problem was just misformating. Our dear OP still doesn't get how to use the editor (after asking 12 questions).

Comment: Btw: Use `dbDelta()` to create the table as shown [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26468/problem-creating-a-table-with-dbdelta).

Comment: activating debug mode in wp-config, when i try to activate my plugin i get this message:The plugin generated 754 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Works perfectly when this code is in main plugin file:

```
<?php
function createTable(){
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " . $wpdb->prefix ."UsersExtra (
        user_id INT NOT NULL,
        first_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        last_name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
        address VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
        city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        province CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
        postcode CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
        interests TEXT NULL,
        bio TEXT NULL,
        signature TEXT NULL,
        skills TEXT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
        FULLTEXT KEY (interests, skills)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8";
    $wpdb->query($query);
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'createTable');
```