# Only allow plugin to be activated on root site of multisite

Tags: plugin-development, multisite, activation

I'm developing the [wordpress file monitor plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-file-monitor-plus/) plugin.

Its purpose is to scan for altered files and it works fine for a single installation of WP. But when you look at multi-site it's not something that wants to be enabled on all sub sites, as they all share the same files and (to be honest) only a network admin should be the one that wants to be notified against file changes.

So my question is this:

> How would I program it, to only be allowed to be installed/run from the root site of a multi-site installation? So: that means not allowing it to be network installed and only activated from the root blog.

Anyone know of any ways on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Per [my answer to this duplicate question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/257262/16121), you can also simply set `Network: true` in the plugin file's PHP header. This should allow the plugin to be activated on non-Multisite installations, but only allow it to be network-activated on Multisite networks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check if the constant `SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE` matches `get_current_site()->id`. The following does this for the activation. During runtime you have to check it again.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'force_main_site_installation' );

function force_main_site_installation()
{
    if ( defined( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE' )
        and SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE !== get_current_site()->id 
    )
    {
        if ( function_exists('deactivate_plugins') )
        {
            deactivate_plugins( __FILE__ );
        }
        die( 'Install this plugin on the main site only.' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Toscho. That stuff you put in chat got me started in the correct direction. I'm now working on a class for my plugin that takes care of things if a multisite installation.

Answer (score 0):

First [the explanation for the uninstall/activation/deactivation hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979).

Second: check for `is_blog_installed( $blog_ID );` and then look into all the `get_blog_whatever();` and get_blogaddress_whatever();` functions (I guess you use phpstorm as IDE, so autocomplete for functions should be available to you).

**Edit:** You could also try to restrict the available menu with registering the admin pages with `network_admin_menu()` (triggers only if `is_network_admin()`), `user_admin_menu();` (triggers only if `is_user_admin()`) instead of `admin_menu();`.

Answer (score 0):

Only this solution worked for me :

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__,  function () {
    if ( is_multisite() && ! strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/network/plugins.php' ) ) {
        die ( __( '<script>alert("Activate this plugin only from the NETWORK DASHBOARD.");</script>') );
    }
    // ...............
});
```