# Force plugin to be activated only from multisite network dashboard

Tags: multisite

Is there a way to allow plugin to be activated only from NETWORK DASHBOARD (if using Multisite).

In not multisite, allow to be activated normally.

Answer (score 10):

You can specify that a plugin is Network Only in the plugin's header information.

```
/*
Plugin Name: Name of Plugin
Plugin URI: Link to plugin information
Description: Plugin Description
[...]
Network: Optional. Specify "Network: true" to require that a plugin is activated
       across all sites in an installation. This will prevent a plugin from being
       activated on a single site when Multisite is enabled.
*/
```

See [`get_plugin_data()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_data/).

`Network: true` in a non-multisite plugin will allow the plugin to work (quick test on my local installation confirms that).

You could also try using the `all_plugins` filter to hide it from the plugin list if your site is a Multisite installation and the user isn't in the Network admin screen:

```
add_filter( 'all_plugins', 'wpse257256_hide_my_plugin' );
function wpse257256_hide_my_plugin( $plugins ) {
    if ( is_multisite() && ! is_network_admin() ) {
        unset( $plugins['my-plugin-name/my-plugin-file.php'] );
    }
    return $plugins;
}
```

### Reference

- [`all_plugins` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/all_plugins/)
- [`is_multisite()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_multisite/)
- [`is_network_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_network_admin/)

Comment: Wow!  I'd never seen the `Network: true` header before reading this.  I tested it seems to work in both multisite and non-multisite.  Thanx!

Comment: @Paul'SparrowHawk'Biron -- I'd never noticed the `Network: true` header before either, but then I'd never needed it before. (I found it by accident: I was searching the Developer Guide for `is_network_admin()` and the search suggestions included [`is_network_only_plugin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_network_only_plugin/).)

Comment: This right here is what makes SE so great. This is exactly what I needed!