# Pass custom css class to add_menu_page

Tags: theme-development, add-menu-page

My theme currently uses add_menu_page() in order to display the theme options sections on the left hand admin menu.

I would like to be able to attach a parent css class to the main menu item in order to selectively show/hide the menus for advanced users.

I don't see this documented in the codex so I'm asking here to find out if there is a workaround or undocumented feature that I can utilize.

Any help, much appreciated.

The basic idea is that I have one main menu item and about 8 submenu items. Currently, all the menu items are displayed in the menu. I would like to use custom css to toggle the visibility of the submenu items, however, there is currently no custom id or class that I can use to target my menus.

Comment: I don't get where exactly you want the classes. Can you post the base of your code? And detail the submenu behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** do this via CSS as the underlying functionality would still be there (and thus open for direct access).

I'd rather rewrite the theme in a way that the menu pages are only added if the current user has a certain capability.

```
if (current_user_can( SOME_CAP )) {
    add menu pages ...
}
```

You could even provide a new capability for your theme. Have a look over [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35165/how-do-i-create-a-custom-role-capability), if you're interested in this.