# User capability per post

Tags: capabilities

According to [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can#Parameters) we can perform `current_user_can` checks for certain `post_ID`, but I fail to find any bit of info how to set a capability explicitly for that `post_ID`.

A follow up question - how to set custom capability (for ex. `download_doc`) of the same type that could be later checked by `current_user_can( "download_doc", get_the_ID() );`

Comment: Refer this answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35165/how-do-i-create-a-custom-role-capability

Comment: This is really two questions, you should separate them into two posts for clarity and so that the best answer for each can be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can not (easily) set up a custom capability for a certain post/page ID. What is described in the Codex, are the so-called [*meta capabilities*](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L978) (a set of predefined capabilities with additional arguments/information).

A (not-that-easy) way is to write your own `my_add_cap`, `my_current_user_can`, `my_has_cap` etc. functions.

Regarding your follow-up question...
You could choose to not [add/check the capability](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90781/27722) `download_doc` with an ID as argument, but the unique ID-based capability `download_doc_{$ID}` instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I do it currently. Didn't know about the meta caps and implementing something like these is probably overkill.