# Create database on installation

Tags: database, installation

I'm working on a custom wordpress plugin, but I can't seem to figure out how to create the database when installing the plugin. (Or when updating)

When searching around this is what I came up with, but this doesn't seem to do anything.

```
function to_install() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE to_issues (
        id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name varchar(125) NOT NULL
    );";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
    add_option('to_db_version', TO_VERSION);
}
function to_install_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $welcome_name = "Hello";
    $welcom_text = "Install successfull";
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'to_install');
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'to_install_data');
```

On a side note, when updating the plugin, will this reinstall all the tables? Or will wordpress handle this correctly?

Comment: to_install() is being executed, whenever I try to output something there, it's returning me an error, so for some reason it's not creating the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL command is invalid. The error says:

> WordPress database error: [Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key]
> CREATE TABLE to_issues ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(125) NOT NULL )

Try:

```
$sql ="CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}to_issues (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    name varchar(125) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";
```

Note that `dbDelta()` is *very* particular about what is passed to it. For instance you need two spaces between the `PRIMARY KEY` and `(id)`.

I have added `$wpdb->prefix` to the table - this adds the (user specified) WordPress prefix. It's good practise to use this, as some people have more than one WordPress install in their database.

#### dbDelta

The 'register activation' is hook only fired when the plug-in is activated - but not when the plug-in is upgraded. So when a user deactivates and activates the plug-in, `dbDelta($sql)` is fired - this is intended. `dbDelta` ([see source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L1495)) recognises 'CREATE' queries, and first checks if the table already exists - and if it doesn't, it creates the table.  If the table does exists, it checks that each of the fields match that in the given `$sql`, and if not, updates them. If the field doesn't exist, but is specified in your `$sql`, it is created.

This way you can easily update a table by chaging `$sql`. However, on updating a plug-in, `to_install` won't called - so you need to manually call it on `admin_init` after checking that the current 'database version' (`TO_VERSION`) is an old one. See [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to) for a detailed explanation of activation/deactivation/uninstall/update procedures..

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped, I executed the SQL too, but I didn't get any error at that time.

I also added the prefix later on, didn't realize I had to do this myself.

Comment: I `var_dump`ed the response from `dbDelta`, which gave the error.

Comment: Aha, I just executed the SQL in phpMyAdmin, thanks for the suggestion, it's good for future use.