# What causes the "Are you sure you want to do this?" error with plugins?

Tags: plugins

This is an odd case I've run into.  A site I've had for years started throwing
this "error"  when i try to make certain backend changes.  It seems pervasive -
If i try to install, update, activate or deactivate any plugin.  I can still look at the list of plugins and view their settings, generally.

Any thoughts on where to start looking?

Comment: do you have sufficient permissions to edit?

Comment: I had this error last week but mine was caused by the database I was running reaching the maximum size.

Comment: Yes on the permissions.

Answer (score 7):

This particular message happens when a [nonce](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) check fails.

I'd say the likely cause is a conflict with the referer (as part of nonce security, WP checks to see if the referer was an admin page on the same domain & path).

You can rule this out by defining a custom function in `wp-config.php`:

```
function check_admin_referer($action = -1, $query_arg = '_wpnonce') {
    if ( -1 == $action )
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'You should specify a nonce action to be verified by using the first parameter.' ), '3.2' );

    $adminurl = strtolower(admin_url());
    $referer = strtolower(wp_get_referer());
    $result = isset($_REQUEST[$query_arg]) ? wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST[$query_arg], $action) : false;
    if ( !$result && !(-1 == $action /* skip this: && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0 */) ) {
        wp_nonce_ays($action);
        die();
    }
    do_action('check_admin_referer', $action, $result);
    return $result;
}
```

This implements the standard nonce check, but skips the referer part. If it cures the error message, we've isolated the problem and can work towards a permanent fix.

[Further reading on the two primary types of errors](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/obscure-wordpress-errors-why-where-and-how) (this, and insufficient permissions).

Comment: I know this answer is quite old, but I tried this with Wordpress 4.3.1, and the error remained.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct thing to do but I've created a [new question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213620/are-you-sure-you-want-to-do-this-when-deactivating-all-plugins-in-wordpress-4) focusing on Wordpress 4.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when implementing 'on_activation' code and needed to see my output mid-development.  Well, this is a big no-no and even with an 'exit' statement, wordpress (4) was showing "Are you sure you want to do this?" instead of my dump.  @TheDeadMedic's suggestion got pointed in the right direction, but didn't work in my particular case.  I put the following into my wp-config.php

```
 // =============== FOR DEVELOPMENT ONLY -BEGIN- ================
/* Stop Checking NONCE
Motivation: when trying to see the output in _deactivation, it would show.
*/
function check_admin_referer($action = -1, $query_arg = '_wpnonce') { //https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60977/8972
    return true;  // honey badger don't care (if I'm in development)   
}
// =============== FOR DEVELOPMENT ONLY -END- ================
```

This will basically kill a bunch of otherwise useful security stuff.

BTW - I was following this sample (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/25979/8972) by @kaiser for activating a plugin.

Comment: I hate to think someone might copy and paste that code as a quick workaround for a plugin that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered this can also happen if a `check_admin_referer()` function is being called with invalid arguments somewhere in your site. If you're getting this error and cant find the problem, check your use of `check_admin_referer()` throughout your theme and plugins.

I started getting this error right after I created a new admin options page for my theme. I had added a `check_admin_referer()` inside a new class, and accidentally swapped the 1st and 2nd parameters. I didn't get any error messages from the class itself, but it mysteriously started affecting the saving of options and profiles in pages that didn't even load or call the class I had created. Fixing my call to `check_admin_referer()` immediately solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this issue in my site for set bellow value in php.ini file

```
memory_limit = 128M 
upload_max_filesize = 80M
post_max_size = 80M
```

may be this useful.

Comment: Can you explain how this piece of code answer the question and fix the problem described?