# Nonce failing with second argument

Tags: plugins, nonce

The plugin [Plugin Maker](http://www.cesarserna.com/wordpress-plugins/plugin-maker/) <sup>[pastebin](http://pastebin.com/G2XSjvVN)</sup> is not working and I've narrowed it down to its nonce-mechanism failing.

At one point it checks for

```
check_admin_referer('$pluginmaker_nonce', $pluginmaker_nonce);
```

which is where it fails. (it gives an error "Are you sure you want to do this")

I've noticed that if you leave out the second argument (`$pluginmaker_nonce`) it works. (the default argument value is [`'_wpnonce'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_admin_referer).)

The way `$pluginmaker_nonce` is defined is

```
if (!function_exists('wp_nonce_field')){
    function pluginmaker_nonce_field($action = -1){
        return;
        }
    $pluginmaker_nonce = -1;
    }
else {
    function pluginmaker_nonce_field($action = -1){
        wp_nonce_field($action);
        }
    $pluginmaker_nonce = 'pluginmaker-nonce-key';
    }
```

Comment: Have a look here, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60957/what-causes-the-are-you-sure-you-want-to-do-this-error-with-plugins

Comment: @Wyck Tested, it's not because of that (still gives that error). But I think it's more because how `pluginmaker-nonce-key` is totally different from `_wpnonce`. `$pluginmaker_nonce` seems to me is defined ..weird.

Answer (score 1):

PHP variables inside single quotes -- `'` -- won't be expanded.  So in your first code snippet, unless you literally mean to pass the string `$pluginmaker_nonce` to the `check_admin_referer()` function as the action, you should probably rewrite your code as `check_admin_referer( 'action_name', $pluginmaker_nonce );`.

Comment: [Fails on `check_admin_referer($pluginmaker_nonce, $pluginmaker_nonce);`.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lVLWE.png)    
[Fails on `check_admin_referer('pluginmaker-nonce-key', $pluginmaker_nonce);`.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zkNA9.png)    
[Works on `check_admin_referer('$pluginmaker_nonce');`.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YUh0s.png)    
Weird...