# "Are you sure you want to do this?" when deactivating all plugins in Wordpress 4.3.1

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, errors

- Wordpress version 4.3.1, running in network mode.
- Logged in as super admin.
- In the main site's dashboard.

When I try to deactivate all active plugins at once, I am taken to a white screen with the message

> "Are you sure you want to do this?"

I have tried adding the following code to `/wp-config.php` mentioned in [this quite old answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60977/3206), but the issue remains.

```
function check_admin_referer($action = -1, $query_arg = '_wpnonce') {
    if ( -1 == $action )
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'You should specify a nonce action to be verified by using the first parameter.' ), '3.2' );

    $adminurl = strtolower(admin_url());
    $referer = strtolower(wp_get_referer());
    $result = isset($_REQUEST[$query_arg]) ? wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST[$query_arg], $action) : false;
    if ( !$result && !(-1 == $action /* skip this: && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0 */) ) {
        wp_nonce_ays($action);
        die();
    }
    do_action('check_admin_referer', $action, $result);
    return $result;
}
```

It's a pain deactivating / reactivating plugins in small groups during troubleshooting.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: I narrowed it down to the error occurring when deactivating [Enhanced E-commerce for Woocommerce store](https://wordpress.org/plugins/enhanced-e-commerce-for-woocommerce-store/) at the same time as any other plugin. I will follow this up on their support page.

Comment: How many plugins do you have? [Do you have debugging information?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95983/21376)

Comment: Hi @s_ha_dum. I activated `debug.log`, and it has 1010 lines of errors generated by `mainwp` & `bloom`, all generated today. I have too many plugins I care to admit to, but the culprit is in the comment above yours.

Comment: FWIW, the ticket for the `Enhanced Ecommerce Google Analytics Plugin for WooCommerce` issue [is here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/are-you-sure-you-want-to-do-this-when-deactivating-this-plus-any-other-plugin?replies=1#post-7842833).

Answer (score 2):

Problem found to be caused by the plugin `Enhanced Ecommerce Google Analytics Plugin for WooCommerce` version 1.0.16.

I gather the fact that this version of the plugin has not been tested with Wordpress 4.3.1 has something to do with the problem.