# Show a confirm message before plug-in activation

Tags: plugins, activation, deactivated-plugin

I want to display a message when the user try to activate my plugin. This message will ask if him really wants to activate the plugin or, if him change his mind, cancel the activation. How can I accomplish that?
This is the code for the warning message just for reference.

--- UPDATED CODE ---

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'on_activation' );

function on_activation() {
   // Add the admin notice:
   add_action( 'admin_notices', 'on_activation_note' );

   // Then you should check the DB option: 
   $plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' );

   // Do all the checks from the confirmation message
   if ( !in_array(__FILE__, $plugins) ) {
   unset( $plugins[ dirname( __FILE__ ) ] );
   update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins );
   }
}

function on_activation_note() {
global $pagenow;
if ( $pagenow == 'plugins.php' ) {
    ob_start(); ?>
    <div id="message" class="error">
    <p><strong>Aviso</strong></br>
    Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
    <p><span><a class="button" href="">Cancelar</a></span>
    <span><a class="button" href="">Continuar</a></span></p>
    </div>
    <?php
    echo ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't actually ask a question... Is there some specific part you're having a problem with, or do you just not know where to start? I'd recommend reading the About page and FAQ to learn about the mechanics of how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

You can read more about the details of [activation on this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979).

Basically you need to hook a function to [`register_activation_hook()`](http://queryposts.com/function/register_activation_hook/) - assuming, that this is from within your main plugin folder and not a subfolder:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'on_activation' );
function wpse65190_on_activation()
{
   // Add an admin notice:
   add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse65190_on_activation_note' );

   // Then you should check the DB option: 
   $plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' );

   if ( ! in_array( dirname( __FILE__ ), $plugins )
   {
       unset( $plugins[ dirname( __FILE__ ) ] );
       update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins );
   }
}
function wpse65190_on_activation_note()
{
    // Add your note here: Maybe a form?
}
```

It's as easy as that. You just have to fill in the gaps. If you got a full working example, please update this answer with your working code. Thanks.

Comment: Well I'm not a programmer, but I can see that your code really makes sense. I changed the "if (!$confirmed)" to "if (!in_array(__FILE__, $plugins))" and place my error message inside the function wpse65190_on_activation_note as you describe, but I'm getting a message "The plugin generated x characters of unexpected output"... What's wrong? =)

Comment: That's because of the `echo`. Just `return` instead.

Comment: I replace the echoes to returns, but get the same error message. =(

Comment: Then you got an error somewhere else. Make sure to turn on every WP and php error display function. This message _only_ appears if something echos (or throws an error) on activation. I'm 110% sure.

Comment: You'r right! I found a function that was causing the error. Now the error is gone, but the admin message still not appear. My debug file show this error: "PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() [<a href='function.call-user-func-array'>function.call-user-func-array</a>]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'on_activation' was given in /home/..."

Comment: That means that the hooked function wasn't found.

Comment: Ok! I get rid of all errors, and the hook is right, but still no messages... =(

Comment: Update your question with current code. (append it with *edit*)

Comment: Ok, simply drop the output buffer.

Comment: made no difference... =(

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two distinctions *activated* and *enabled*. You **HAVE TO** have your plugin activated AKA included for WP to know what logic to process.  Even though the plugin is activated, you can still disable functionality and alert the user that the plugin is *activated*, but not yet *enabled*.

There are several plugins that use a secondary step of enabling. You can take a look at [Private WP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/private-wordpress/) and [All-In-One SEO Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/) to see how they accomplish this.

Here's how I would approach it:

1. Set an admin notice once the plugin is activated alerting the user they need to enable the functionality first.
2. If a certain query string is set, add an option that notes they've elected to *enable* the functionality (i.e. `update_option()`). You might want to create a settings page with a select drop-down that shows its enable state.
3. Check that option using `get_option()` to disable the admin notice and continue processing your code.