# Uninstall script for a plugin in Multisite

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I've just realized that the traditional [`uninstall.php`](http://wpengineer.com/35/wordpress-plugin-deinstall-data-automatically/) file along a plugin is not working in Multisite.

```
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) 
    exit();

delete_option( 'plugin_option_name' );
```

This doesn't delete the sub-sites options in all `wp_SITE-ID_options` tables.

Is there a standard way for doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching inside all `uninstall.php` files that I have in my hard-drive, I've found two that had the function `is_multisite()`: [User Role Editor](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/user-role-editor/trunk/uninstall.php) and [Add Code to Head](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/add-code-to-head/trunk/uninstall.php).

Both use a `$wpdb` loop. Simplified:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Uninstall Procedure
 */

// Make sure that we are uninstalling
if ( !defined( 'WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN' ) ) 
    exit();

// Leave no trail
$option_name = 'plugin_option_name';

if ( !is_multisite() ) 
{
    delete_option( $option_name );
} 
else 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $blog_ids = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT blog_id FROM $wpdb->blogs" );
    $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    foreach ( $blog_ids as $blog_id ) 
    {
        switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
        delete_option( $option_name );     

        // OR
        // delete_site_option( $option_name );  
    }

    switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );
}
```

Related Q&A: [Uninstall, Activate, Deactivate a plugin: typical features & how-to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25910/12615)

Comment: You shold use [`restore_current_blog`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog) instead of storing the current blog id and switching back later

Comment: @bungeshea, yes, much more elegant :) I was about to edit the Answer but am wondering: Multisite `uninstall.php` won't run always from blog ID == 1?

Comment: You can only delete plugins from the network dashboard, which is on the main site (blog id 1)

Comment: Yep, sure, and, after all, it's nonsense using `switch_to_blog(1)` when we have the `restore_` function... Don't recall exactly where I read something about changing the main blog instance...

Comment: Have you tested this thoroughly? Looking at the source code, it would seem the `uninstall.php` file within a plugin would only be called if 1) it existed prior to the plugins activation (if so, the plugin name would be stored within the blog's option table); 2) when calling `get_option('uninstall_plugins')` actually yields that specific plugin. It doesn't seem to work on Multisite because network-wide plugin info is stored in the `sitemeta` table, instead.

Comment: @tbuteler : 0) No, not thoroughly. 1) Why would `uninstall.php` not exist prior to plugin activation. Seems an edge case. 2) Updated the Answer to include `delete_site_option`, if that's the case of the plugin. The one I was testing needed `delete_option`...

Comment: 1) I meant for debugging purposes -- if someone developing a plugin is wondering why his `uninstall.php` file isn't being loaded on deactivation, this is the first scenario to consider; 2) That's not really what I meant; I think the problem is on WP's end (i.e. it's checking the wrong table to see which plugins have uninstall routines), but I might be wrong.

Comment: @tbuteler : 1) [`This file will be called, if it exists, during the uninstall process bypassing the uninstall hook.`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook). 2) I think `1)` covers this too...

Comment: I don't think that a site option would need to be deleted in the loop. It is a network wide option.