# Show a confirmation message on plugin deactivation

Tags: plugins, deactivation

When my plugin is deactivated, I want to get a confirmation from the user whether all plugin options/tables need to be deleted or left as it is. Based on the option selected, I want to proceed further. Is it possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Yes it is possible but don't confuse deactivation for uninstall.  They are two very different things.  You actually don't want to delete anything when a plugin is deactivated.  When they uninstall is when you want to ask the user if they want to delete settings.  Look into the register_uninstall_hook

Comment: There is a discussion here which doesn't directly answer your question but will certainly help with your question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979

Comment: @Matt.C Yes, I have gone thru the link but did not serve my purpose. Thanx though :)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a workaround with JavaScript. I'm loading my own JavaScript file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('wp-deactivation-message', plugins_url('js/message.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array());
```

which contains a script that adds following Event Listener - when user clicks on our plugin deactivate button it prevent it from performing this action and display a JavaScript popup asking what you need, if user accepts it will be deactivated, if user press `'cancel'` nothing happens:

> message.js

```
window.onload = function(){
        document.querySelector('[data-slug="plugin-name-here"] a').addEventListener('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault()
            var urlRedirect = document.querySelector('[data-slug="plugin-name-here"] a').getAttribute('href');
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to save this thing into the database?')) {
                window.location.href = urlRedirect;
            } else {
                console.log('Ohhh, you are so sweet!')
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('[data-slug="plugin-name-here"] a')` is not perfect, there could be more than one links inside the div with data-slug, like deactivate, delete or more. It should be more like: `document.querySelector('[data-slug="plugin-name-here"] .deactivate a')`

Comment: Does this work with an uninstall.php process that deletes options? What I'd really like to see is a choice to 'delete plugin and options' and 'delete plugin/keep options' and 'cancel' when someone hits the Delete on the admin/plugins screen (after deactivating).

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble with the `dirname(__FILE__)` for some reason, so I changed my code to this, where bkj-functions is my plugin slug.

`wp_enqueue_script('wp-deactivation-message', plugins_url('js/message-deactivate.js', __FILE__), array());`

with the following contents for `js/message-dactivate.js` (since I only need an "Alert" and not a "Confirm"):

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.querySelector('[data-slug="bkj-functions"] .deactivate a').addEventListener('click', function(event){
        //event.preventDefault()
        alert("Reminder: If you are using the 'class' taxonomy for styling, that may disappear when this plugin has been deactivated.")
    })
}
```