# Manually Removing Plugins

Tags: plugins

Are there any special procedures needed to remove a plugin manually?

I have some plugins I need to remove but can't access the `/wp-admin` area till they are removed.

Answer (score 2):

Addition to @PatJ answer:

Keep in mind that an uninstall/deactivation functions won't trigger. So in case the plugin(s) in question leave back a lot of DB entries, you'll have to manually clean up the DB.

Another option would (maybe) be to use [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) and try to manually trigger any uninstall functions. This will only work for plugins not properly coded, because if they are, then the functions [won't trigger if it isn't a uninstall task](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979) or the nonce checks will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign in to your site via FTP or SSH and move the plugin files/directories from the WordPress plugin directory (normally `wp-content/plugins`).  If the files are missing, I believe WordPress will deactivate the plugin automatically.

**Edited to add**: As @Milo suggests, you can also simply rename the plugin's file/folder.  For instance, if you're using a plugin whose folder is named `myplugin`, changing it to `broken.myplugin` will cause WordPress to deactivate your plugin.

See [Managing Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins) for more details.

Comment: or just rename the file/directory and it will be deactivated, no need to move anything.