# ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser

Tags: cookies

I'm getting this error while trying to log in:

> ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must
>   enable cookies to use WordPress.

Yet I have cookies enabled and not blocked. I've tried this on a few different browsers, and in the incognito/private modes of those browsers, too, and get the same messages. I've also tried clearing all cookies from the cache, pursuant to the instructions on [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-say-cookies-are-blocked-unblock-them). What could be causing this, and how would I go about debugging this issue?

Comment: Disable your plugins and switch to a bundled theme like "Twenty Fourteen". Do you still have the problem?

Comment: Please file an [edit] and show your `wp-config.php` file. Also do as @s_ha_dum said: Deactivate plugins, etc.

Comment: @kaiser, Thanks, that was it. It was a domain set incorrectly in `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out I had `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` set incorrectly in `wp-config.php`. (This particular install was a copy of another server, and the domain hadn't fully been changed.)

Comment: I had the same problem with cookies during login but my case was a rewrite plugin which after renaming plugin folder from ftp wp-content/plugins/rewrite to broken.rewrite as is explained here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119590/manually-removing-plugins/119591#119591 finally I am able to login.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have the wrong values for `siteurl` and/or `home` in your `wp_options` table. Make sure these values match the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE` noted above.

Answer (score 0):

The exact fix for the issue is to update this code:

```
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

in wp-config.php, but the important point in pasting is that you should
exactly past the above code on a new line after this code in wp-config.php file.

```
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_KEY',  'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_KEY',    'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_KEY',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'AUTH_SALT',        'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'SECURE_AUTH_SALT', 'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'LOGGED_IN_SALT',   'put your unique phrase here' );
define( 'NONCE_SALT',       'put your unique phrase here' );
```

Save and refresh the admin login page. Enter your correct credentials, all is well.