# Users cannot post when editor or admin on more than 1 site on multisite

Tags: posts, multisite

Just upgraded to 3.6.1 last week. I have rolled back and re-upgraded 2 times. When I roll back everything works. I've Turned off plugins, changed to 2012 theme. Tried 3.7 with same issues.

Users can create posts in post-new page no problem UNLESS they are editor, admin etc on another blog in the multisite. If I remove a user from a second site they can immediately post in the first and vice versa.

They can use quick press from the dashboard to add a post and are able to edit without issue.

The post object is not created or fails to create when the user is on two blogs.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\Websites\wp-admin\includes\post.php on line 471 stdClass Object ( [post_content] => [post_title] => [post_excerpt] => [post_name] => ) 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$ID in D:\Websites\wp-admin\post-new.php on line 73
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_date in D:\Websites\wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php on line 52 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_date in D:\Websites\wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php on line 65 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_status in D:\Websites\wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php on line 90 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_status in D:\Websites\wp-admin\edit-form-advanced.php on line 124 Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type in D:\Websites\wp-includes\taxonomy.php on line 169 
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$post_type in D:\Websites\wp-includes\taxonomy.php
```

Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're saying you've tried reinstalling?

Comment: I have rolled back the upgrade and applied again. I have not completely re-installed with db and all. How would I do that without losing all my data?

Comment: There's no native way to "roll back" unless you mean roll back in VCS terms. But if so you'll have to keep in mind that VCS saves _any_ history and that does include corrupted or incomplete files. Just go to Dashboard > Update and then reinstall. This shouldn't touch your DB, but you better perform an update (and check if it's valid and working).

Comment: Another thing I could imagine is that you were hacked and your data connection isn't working (which would maybe explain that there're no posts fetched).

Comment: I did manual re-installs. I can see posts. Users can create posts if they use quick press on the dashboard. Users that are admins, editors etc that are on more than one blog in the multisite cannot post on the add new post page only using quickpress. THe reason is that the post object doesn't insert into the db for some reason when a user is on more than one blog.

Comment: Oh AND I have two multisites and this is happening on both after upgrading to 3.6.1. The front ends are fine and admins, editors etc can edit posts with no issues.

Comment: What is a "manual reinstall"? And I think that you might have had some plugin or theme installed that messed with the user capabilities and roles.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can read in your question and the comments, the problem seems to come from the database, not from the theme or a plugin. WordPress users, roles and capabilities are actually saved in the DataBase.

Whenever you install a plugin, that doesn't reset the things it altered (or you altered while using it), your installation will be left with those changes. Sadly there're lots of plugins not [cleaning up after themselves](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979). Sometimes there're even themes doing stuff that should (but can not) be reserved to plugins.

A logical (not programmatic) way to debug your problem and find a solution would be to install *any* plugin that shows you a list of roles and the assigned capabilities. At the current moment there're already some in the wp dot org plugin repository (role managers and such) or [you could write your own](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=get+role+capabilities). When you got something written or downloaded and installed, your best bet would be to locally set up a plain vanilla install that only has this plugin active. Then manually compare your roles and capabilities and see where it fails or in other words, try to fix the missing roles and/or user and/or role capabilities.

Keep in mind that the existing role manager plugins won't care about "mapped" capabilities, special post type capability stuff and so on. So there still could be some glitches if you don't inspect every aspect. Which leaves me with the last note: Go through your backups and install one of the copies where this problem doesn't occur.