# Best practice to create required pages

Tags: theme-development, templates, customization

Some times, when we work on custom wordpress themes, we need required pages. For example - custom login page. Some times, when user change slug, page template or something else - it a very difficult to find. Or user can delete this page :)
Also this can be problem, when you have custom links for this pages on another pages.
I want to find solution for manage this. I can paste our code that we use for this.

Comment: Please add comments not just down grade the question :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Themes should not create content. Ever. That is [plugin territory](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/73031/73).

When you [activate the plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/25910/73), search for pages with a special custom field. Its name should start with an underscore, so it doesn’t show up in the *Custom Fields* metabox, for example `_pluginslug_required_page`. If there are no such pages, create your own.

But I would question the underlying problem. Why do you **need** those pages? There are very few cases where that is really needed, a *cart* page in an e-commerce plugin maybe. A theme should work without such an requirement.

Comment: Hello @toscho!
We are your fans!
Thanks for your answer, I want to add more information to you!

For example we have custom templates for custom pages like(here the slug of pages): "login", "registration", "forgot-password", "login-2", "registration-2". 

If we`ll put a link to login page at registration page like `code get_permalink('login') ` - If we remove this page - this link will be displayed, but not work fine(generate 404 error).
Same things if i change the slug of the page.
Another problem - if page will be deleted - we`ll not been notified in any ways(like errors, etc.)

Comment: can you tell me, how was created pages like cart, checkout at WooCommerce plugin? With custom post meta field?