# How to Add an Index to Plugin Database table

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database

I've created some additional tables for a plugin I'm developing and need to add indexes to these tables.

What's the WordPress way to do this?

Using [`dbDelta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/) doesn't seem to be working, and I'm not seeing any error in the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute *arbitrary* SQL statements with [wpdb::query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/), including Data Definition Statements, e.g.

```
function
create_index ()
{
    global $wpdb ;

    $sql = "CREATE INDEX my_index ON {$wpdb->prefix}my_table (my_column)" ;

    $wpdb->query ($sql) ;

    return ;
}
```

**Note:** Because `$wpdb->query()` can execute *arbitrary* SQL, if the statement you pass to it contains **ANY** user input, then you should use [wpdb::prepare()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) to protect against SQL Injection attacks.

But this raises the question: how did you create your plugin-specific tables?  "Manually" or programmatically?  If programmatically, did you not use `$wpdb->query()`?  If you did it "manually", then you really should create the tables (and their indexes) upon plugin activation.

See the excellent answer to [this other WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25910/uninstall-activate-deactivate-a-plugin-typical-features-how-to/25979#25979) for how to hook into plugin activation (and/or deactivation and uninstall) to do things like create private tables.

Comment: Thanks for answering this question even though it's 5 months old. I ended up doing this but wasn't sure if it was the "right way". Will be a big help the next time I try to do this.

Comment: @Milk My pleasure.  I figured you'd either already solved your problem or had given up :-)  I answered it (even tho 5mos after you asked) to help others who have the same problem and search WPSE and come across your question.

Answer (score 10):

Using dbDelta, on top of a PRIMARY KEY, you can include the word KEY to create an index for other columns:

> You must use the key word KEY rather than its synonym INDEX and you must include at least one KEY.

Example from schema.php in core:

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->termmeta (
  meta_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  term_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  meta_key varchar(255) default NULL,
  meta_value longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY  (meta_id),
  KEY term_id (term_id),
  KEY meta_key (meta_key($max_index_length))
) $charset_collate;
```

Source: [codex - Creating Tables with Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins)