# How to use WP_Error $data argument?

Tags: errors, api

#### The Call

```
$error = new WP_Error( $code, $message, $data );
```

#### The Output

Say I added three messages (msg A, msg B, msg C) to the code `my_code` and with the last message I added "Data" as `$data`, which overwrote all `$data` added with the previous calls to the error class.

```
WP_Error Object
(
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [my_code] => Array
                (
                    [0] => "msg A"
                    [1] => "msg B"
                    [2] => "msg C"
                )
        )
    [error_data] => Array
        (
            [my_code] => "Data"
        )
)
```

After inspecting & playing around with the wp error class, I came to the following Qs:

#### Problem

I can pass an unlimited number of `$code`s to the class and then pass an unlimited number of `$message`s to each code. Point is that I can't pass more than one `$data` per `$code`.

**Q:** What is the intended use case of `$data`?<sup>1)</sup>

---

<sup>1) Currently I'm trying to build a pretty simple WP_Error wrapper API (basically a set of easy-to-use functions). The Goal is to make a trac ticket out of it and move it to WP core.</sup>

---

#### Edit #1

I found a pretty strange behaviour in /wp-includes/functions.php with the `wp_die();` function: If you provide an error object, the function automatically fills the title provided by `$data['title']`. So from looking at this I thought that `$data` could be an associative array that can hold any amount of additional, dynamic data.

**Q:** But - and this is only valid if this is the intended use case - if `$data` is a) an array and b) I successfully added additional data in there: How would I connect that to the according messages?

**Q:** Further: Why doesn't `wp_die();` abort if I have no error? This makes using it as dynamically - in case - added error output completely invalid.

---

#### Edit #2

You can find the ticket to fix the `wp_die()` handler [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19073).

---

#### Edit #3

A draft of a first "Theme Errors API" can be found [here on github](https://gist.github.com/1322989). Forking, etc. and commenting is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

`$this->error_data[$code]` ... the WP_Error object holds $data in an array and $code is the key. The `add_data` method clearly states:

> The error code can only contain one error data. But the `$data` (mixed) can be an array or an object and carry as many keys/properties as you need. It's up to your handlers how they interpret it.

Error `$data` is a bonus for further custom processing of the error. Your own special function can throw a `WP_Error` and you can add custom data into the `$data` that can be interpreted by your error own handler.

`wp_die();` is the same as `die;` only that it shows formatted output before doing so. It is expected TO DIE. `die;` in PHP is not conditional. It's meant to stop there and `wp_die();` is designed to mimic functionality with advanced pre-death output capabilities.

The `'title'` in the `$data` support is just a bonus allowing built-in title support for the `WP_Error()`. It's designed so they don't need to choose which `error_code`'s message is the title if multiple are present. They just use the default one's title attribute. NEVER RELY ON SUCH DEFAULT FUNCTIONALITY! Always use your own title in `wp_die()`.

*No errors here, just intended behavior... if I understood your question right.*

Comment: Hm. Relying on default behavior/functionality imo isn't bad. When you click the link to the ticket in the Q and then look into core code for `_default_wp_die_handler();`, you see that every custom `$title` would avoid calling `wp_die();` only in case an error is present. I'm currently making coffee, re-reading your above answer and then answer to it. Btw: The double brackets symbol in the editor is meant to be used for "code" (instead of bold). So far: Thanks for the answer. Discussion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't read support tickets (narrations of code). I read code :) And that's what the wp_die(); code told me. Anyways, the 3.2.1 version.

Comment: Ehm, yea. The Q is _about tickets_. :)

Comment: Consider increasing the font on the ticket link. wp_die(); must always die. They should not change that. It's up to you to count errors before feeding the WP_Error object to wp_die(). The more you try to offload your work, the more prone to errors the 'universal' solution becomes. Seriously, it's just an IF.

Comment: What's the use case of an empty `wp_die();` page? Also: The function `wp_die();` already counts the errors. So why should I count something before feeding `WP_Error`? Makes no sense - even not before feeding `wp_die()` - unless I missunderstood something. Ad font-size: done. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Because wp_die; must die, just like Romeo. It would be a compatibility nightmare to make wp_die; conditional.

Comment: "(...)just like Romeo" :) good one! Anyway: `wp_die();` is just a wrapper for the `wp_die_handler` filter, so you can override it and therefore it's not a "must" and the compability nightmare is intended. And from looking at core code it simply is a mess at current state. Else is listed in comment above.

Comment: I wrote a 3rd Edit. Maybe you want to give me some input.

Comment: You want to reserve a new WP_Error global object to use just for theme Errors? And you want to display errors gathered... on shutdown if specific capabilities exist and DEBUG conditions are met?

Comment: You completely got me. The global object exists because of the draft. Not sure if it's necessary. Could also double the `$code` object (see `if` switch on add function).

Comment: I'll post a reply later on. Doing something right now. You're doing it sort of wrong. Once you have a global theme error object, you don't need a custom named code. There's one theme active at a time. So you could just to the following:

Comment: Still waiting for your _following_ code(?)...

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Creates a static global shared WP_Error object.
 * The object is contained safely inside function body as static variable.
 * It's also protected from external influence.
 * 
 * @return WP_Error
 */
function theme_errors(){
    static $wp_error; // Will hold global variable safely
    return isset($wp_error) ? $wp_error : ($wp_error = new WP_Error(null, null, null));
}
// This is how you add errors (first call initializes the object).
theme_errors()->add($code = 'code', $message = 'message', $data = 'some data');
theme_errors()->add($code = 'code', $message = 'message', $data = 'some data');
// And then do some display stuff on shutdown
add_action('shutdown', function(){
    // If conditions are met and errors exist:
    if(!theme_errors()->get_error_codes()) return;
    // Loop error codes and display errors
    foreach(($codes = theme_errors()->get_error_codes()) as $code){
        $message = theme_errors()->get_error_message($code);
        $data = theme_errors()->get_error_data($code);
        // Display stuff here
    }
});
```

Much easier alternative. Theme name independent *(we only work with active theme)*. Protected global variable inside function.