# Get Core Functionality from Within a (Secondary) Plugin File

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-load.php

I have a plugin with the following structure:

```
myplugin.php
   includes/authentication.php
```

I can access core WordPress functionality inside myplugin.php fine, but when I try to access stuff such as `add_action('init', 'myaction')` inside authentication.php, I receive a PHP error.

I tried including the WordPress wp-load.php file in order to gain core functionality, but the WordPress repository doesn't accept plugins that load wp-config or wp-load files.

What is the best way to proceed in this situation and why don't I have access to core WordPress functions from a plugin that is loaded.

Comment: Please include the full scenario of what you are trying to achieve. Right now it sounds like you are trying to access the URL of includes/authentication.php which is a big NO NO.

Comment: [Best practices for plugin development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/715/12615) . . . .

Comment: @MarkKaplun This is exactly what I was trying to achive. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You should include your `includes/authentication.php` in your `myplugin.php` like that:

```
include('includes/authentication.php');
```

You can use all the WordPress-Functions there.

If there are any specific functions that don't work for you, please list them, and show us how you included your `includes/authentication.php`.

Comment: I decided to go down another path: Registering a custom admin page in myplugin.php and including the code that was inside authentication.php in the callback function (the one that displays the custom page). However, I've [stumbled upon something](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88275/can-not-redirect-from-plugin-registered-admin-page).