# Adding functions to hooks from within a class

Tags: plugin-development, customization

Below is a trimmed down version of my plugin, to keep it simple. My setup function is being called, but when I go to the login page, it's not dying like it should. I had the plugin working earlier, however I'm trying to re-write it into a class structure to make it more self-contained.

```
if ( ! function_exists('add_action') ) {
   header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
   header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', array('My_Authentication', 'setup') );
if ( ! class_exists('My_Authentication') ) {
    class My_Authentication {
        public function setup() {
            add_action('wp_login', array(&$this, 'no_auth_allowed') );
            add_action('wp_logout', array(&$this, 'no_auth_allowed') );
        }
        public function no_auth_allowed() {
            wp_die('no authentication for you!');
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify on what my question is, why isn't the `no_auth_allowed()` function being called when I go to the `wp-login.php` page?

Comment: If the syntax error on the `add_action('wp_logout',` line is corrected does it work?

Comment: See the two class examples on [`add_action`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action). You can't call a class method like that.

Comment: I thought so too @Milo, but I pasted it into a mu-plugin file and the `setup()` method fires.

Comment: @s_ha_dum thanks, I fixed the typo, but the problem still persists.

Comment: I started by looking at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1189/80697) to try and understand how to properly do the add_actions.

Comment: it works if I create an instance of the class and move the `add_action` to after the instance is created. I get invalid `call_user_func` error otherwise.

Comment: @Milo could you submit an answer with how you did it? It's still not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a class instance and referenced that in `add_action`, which is moved below where the instance is created:

```
if ( ! function_exists('add_action') ) {
   header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
   header('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden');
}

if ( ! class_exists('My_Authentication') ) {
    class My_Authentication {
        public function setup() {
            add_action('wp_login', array(&$this, 'no_auth_allowed') );
            add_action('wp_logout', array(&$this, 'no_auth_allowed') );
        }
        public function no_auth_allowed() {
            wp_die('no authentication for you!');
        }
    }
    $my_auth = new My_Authentication;
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', array($my_auth, 'setup') );
```

Comment: It's still doing the same thing for me. This is causing your wp-login.php page to die?

Comment: you have to try to log in, the `wp_login` action fires when in the process of logging in, not just visiting the login page.

Comment: weird, I could've sworn it triggered when the page loaded. I'll just have to find a new hook for my needs. Thanks for the help!